# Ring Doorbell Not Getting Enough Power

Tags: transformer, doorbell

My ring wired doorbell is not getting enough power. The transformer has multiple options but is currently set at 8V 20VA and the chime state 16VAC 10VA.

Can I switch the load of the transformer to 16V 30VA?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is preventing you from moving the wires?

Comment: Nothing just wanted to make sure it wouldn’t cause any harm first.

Comment: It i up to the door bell if it can handle 16 Volt, look it up

Answer (score 2):

Sure, go ahead and switch it to the 16 volt tap. The chime only cares about the voltage and having enough capacity in volt-amps to run it properly. If you have more capacity than you need it won't hurt anything in the doorbell circuit.

Comment: You also want to be a whole lot more careful about how much unsheathed wire you have hanging out from those terminals.

Answer (score 0):

From the installation guide:

Your Doorbell Wired is
compatible with doorbell
systems supplying 10–24
volts AC, at 50 or 60Hz, 40VA
max. The AC connector is
the class 2 energy source.

Change it to 16.